# How to detect which identity provider send a response

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect

Currently, I'm trying to implement an OpenID Connect solution which supports multiple identity providers. I chose to use the authorization code flow for this.

When the user opens the login screen the logo's of the supported identity providers are visible. When a logo/identity provider is clicked the system will store the necessary cookies and will redirect the user to the identity provider.

The response of the identity provider contains the following information:

1. Authorization code
2. Session_state
3. State
4. Scope

Now if I want to make a token request I don't know which identity provider to use. Some things I thought of two things to solve this issue:

1. Using the UrlReferrer
2. Storing the used provider in the cookies(Encrypted).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the provider details in session or in cookies would be the better option I guess as you might need to use other endpoints (such as introspection, certification) later in the flow.

Comment: After reading the following article [link](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bradley-oauth-jwt-encoded-state-08.html#rfc.section.2) I noticed that using the optional audience claim in the OAuth2 state is intended for storing the client(provider) the state is intended for. But should there not be a better way for doing this?

Comment: Client is not the identity provider. `aud` claim in the token returns the application(s) which a user authorizes to access a certain resource on his behalf. This client should also be registered as a client in your IdP. Since the tokens returned are in the form of `jwt`, you can validate the signature to determine whether the token has been tampered with.